# Why does number of turns not matter for magnetic field in toroidal coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I am trying to understand why the magnetic field of a toroidal coil does not depend on the total number of turns.

In my book it states:

[image]

And so it concluded that ${H=  I/ 2{\pi}r}$

Where as my attempt was:

${H * 2{\pi}r=NI}$ so ${H=NI/2{\pi}r}$

I am a bit confused why number of turns is not a factor here, like it is for a coil shaped as a solenoid.

I still struggle to visualise this in my mind.

Comment: The integral on the RHS does not evaluate to $\frac{I}{2 \pi r}$

Comment: Are you referring to ${H = I/2{\pi}r}$ if so thats because it was re-arranged to solve for H. In the book it claims the RHS is just ${I}$. As in ${H2{\pi}r = I}$

Comment: hint: As @SenorO says your integral $\int_S J_f dS$ is proportional to $N$...

Answer (score 0):

That is a wrong conclusion. Number of turns do matter.

General case:

$B=μnI$,

where $n=N/l$, N=number of turns and $l=length$ of solenoid.

For toroidal solenoid of radius R, with $l$ length of solenoid and $B_{i}$ magnetic field per segment length of toroidal solenoid, using Ampere's Law:

$
\begin{array}{l}
\sum B_{(\mathrm{i})} l=\mu_{0} I_{en} \\\\
B(2 \pi R)=\mu_{0} N I \\\\
\frac{B(2 \pi R)}{2 \pi R}=\frac{\mu_{0} N I}{2 \pi R} \\\\
B=\frac{\mu_{0} N I}{2 \pi R}
\end{array}
$

[image: toroidal solenoid]

Comment: Wait so are you saying that my solution is correct and the book is actually incorrect?

Comment: I don't think the book is wrong. You may have misinterpreted it or missed some detail in the description and notations used.